# add_settings_field not functioning with validation - returns string

Tags: php, database, wordpress, validation, pdo

The plugin admin panel works fine until I attempt to validate the settings;

```
register_setting('jo_plugin_options', 'jo_plugin_options', array($this, 'jo_validate_settings'));
add_settings_section('jo_main_section', 'Data Table Settings', array($this, 'jo_main_section_cb'), __FILE__); // id, title, section, callback, page
add_settings_field('jo_col_1_name', 'Column 1 Name: ', array($this, 'jo_col_1_name_setting'), __FILE__, 'jo_main_section');
add_settings_field('jo_col_2_name', 'Column 2 Name: ', array($this, 'jo_col_2_name_setting'), __FILE__, 'jo_main_section');
add_settings_field('jo_col_3_name', 'Column 3 Name: ', array($this, 'jo_col_3_name_setting'), __FILE__, 'jo_main_section');
add_settings_field('jo_file_upload', 'Upload File: ', array($this, 'jo_file_upload_setting'), __FILE__, 'jo_main_section');
```

So if I remove the // **array($this, 'jo_validate_settings')** // from the register_setting line my text boxes function fine.  But when I add that validation code, it breaks them and returns this error;

***Warning: Illegal string offset 'jo_col_1_name' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/plugin-rough.php on line 82***

The boxes are here:

```
public function jo_col_1_name_setting() {
echo "<input id='jo_col_1_name' name='jo_plugin_options[jo_col_1_name]' type='text' value='{$this->options['jo_col_1_name']}' />"; }

public function jo_col_2_name_setting() {
echo "<input name='jo_plugin_options[jo_col_2_name]' type='text' value='{$this->options['jo_col_2_name']}' />"; }

public function jo_col_3_name_setting() {
echo "<input name='jo_plugin_options[jo_col_3_name]' type='text' value='{$this->options['jo_col_3_name']}' />"; }
```

I did some reading online and found something semi relevant, someone saying that the keys were the same and I needed to change $this to &$this for it to function.  I tried it and nothing happened, same errors.

Any ideas?

Additionally: Is it necessary to use add_settings_field for each additional field I want to add? Seems like I will be adding a very large amount of these.

var_dump shows me this:

```
string(31) "{$this->options[jo_col_1_name]}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if (!isset($youroptions['somename'])){
$youroptions['somename'] = '';
}  
//or like this
if (!isset($youroptions['somename'])){
 $youroptions['somename']= 'blank';//You can try to use 
}                                  //$youroptions['somename']= 'undefined';
```

Full working example (added inside "Settings" backend) :

```
<?php
add_action('admin_menu','create_theme_options_page');
function create_theme_options_page(){
add_options_page('Theme Options','Theme Options','administrator',__FILE__,'build_options_page');
}
function build_options_page(){
?>
<div id="theme-options-wrap">
<div style="float:left;margin-top:19px;position:absolute;" class="icon32" id="icon-tools"><br/></div>
<h2>My options page</h2>
<form method="post" action="options.php">
<?php settings_fields('plugin_options');?>
<?php do_settings_sections(__FILE__); ?>
<p class="submit">
<input name="Submit" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save changes');?>"/>
</p>
</form>
</div>
<?php
}

add_action('admin_init','register_and_build_fields');
function register_and_build_fields(){
register_setting('plugin_options','plugin_options','validate_setting');
add_settings_section('main_section','<br/><br/>Main Settings','section_cb',__FILE__);
add_settings_field('banner_headings','Banner Heading:','banner_heading_settings',__FILE__,'main_section');

}

//Banner Heading
function banner_heading_settings(){
$options = get_option('plugin_options');
if(isset( $options['banner_headings'])) {
$options = $options['banner_headings'];
} else {
$options='';
}

echo '<input type="text" name="plugin_options[banner_headings]" value="'.$options.'" />';

}
//Return our options back
function validate_setting($plugin_options){ 



return $plugin_options;
}

function section_cb(){
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean use isset on the value of the input?

Comment: Yup try to do it that way. Works for me.

Comment: I gave that a try and the errors disappeared but the data still wont save.  You are right though it has something to do with checking if the value isset before posting.  Is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: I have cleaned my code a bit so now it works better and is more understandable. Have fun.

Comment: Dejo - Thank you! This is weird, but after adding your // return $plugin_options; // to my validate function it all worked.  Is that typical, and something I just overlooked?   I was under the impression that I needed to validate with isset, but maybe wordpress does that by default when using add_setting_field?

Comment: How funny - I am following the tuts+ php training and they neglected to tell me I needed to add that.  In a video training.  :-/ Maybe I should spend my money elsewhere - any recommendations?  What resources did you use to learn what you know about php and wordpress?

Comment: This helped me a lot http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-1/